# Selecting corresponding values from another loop to use in subsequent loop

Tags: matlab

I am an Earth Scientist, and interested in the macro scale morphometric parameters in the river basins. I am building a simple graded Stream Gradient index from a excel sheet. I have wrote a simple code which follows:

```
data = 'SL.xlsx';
headers = xlsread(data);
lat = headers (:,1);
long = headers (:,2);
elevation = headers (:,3);
numberofelement = numel (lat);

% To calculate the intermideate distacne between two points

for i=2:numberofelement
intdistance (1)=0;
intdistance (i) = sqrt((lat (i)-lat (i-1))^2+ (long (i)-long (i-1))^2);
end

% Cumulative distacne in km

cumdist (1)=0

for j=2:numberofelement
cumdist(j)=cumdist(j-1)+intdistance (j);
cumdistkm (j)= cumdist(j)/1000;
end

% Average SL index (or graded river gradient
gradedslindex = (elevation (1)- elevation (numberofelement))/log(cumdistkm(numberofelement))
```

I am unable to to do the next steps. The next steps includes few calculations:

The hypothetical data looks like

**Cumdist Elevation**

```
0.25     500
2.1      480
4.2      470
6.8      450
7.5      430
8.2      420
9.1      410
10.1     400
```

1) In the cumdistkm variable I have to segment for every 5 km. If there is no 5 km value, I have to select the nearest lower value for cumdist. So for this data the 4.2 and 9.1 have to taken.

2) Then the calculation part would be elevation(last)-elevation(first)(for that particular reach) and divide by In(cumdistkm(last))-In(cumdist(first))(for the same row index).

I am unable to select these parameters for regular interval. A small hint is will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you looked at MATLAB's various histogram functions? When looking, also check if they can provide multiple outputs. I would wager that one will let you specify a bin size (in your case `5`) and then output the indices of the breaks.

Comment: I think you need to implement something like [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). Otherwise you will be hundreds of metres of after a few kilometers already. Matlab have something called [mapping toolbox](http://se.mathworks.com/products/mapping/) for this. Apart from this I am not sure what does not work. The guess is that the fact that earth is not completely spheric causes problems that your points are not set as you expect. The loops seems to fo what they should though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cumsum function to find cumdist

```
cumdist_km = [0; cumsum(intdistance)/1000];  %calculate cumdist in km
```

I would make a function and stick it in a file `findIndicesBelowIncrement.m`. There might be a slicker way to do this, but this should be quite fast and works (as I understand what you're asking for).

```
function indices = findIndicesBelowIncrement(cumdist_km, km_increment)
% indices = findIndicesForBelowIncrement(cumdist_km, km_increment)
%        cumdist_km  : sorted array of distances
%        km_increment: we will find index of cumdist_km for each 
%                      multiple of increment such that distance is
%                      at or below the multiple of the increment

indices = NaN(ceil(cumdist_km(end) / 5), 1);  % we know endpoint, lets init smart
j = 1;
for i=2:length(cumdist_km)             % iterate through array
  if(cumdist_km(i) > j * km_increment) % we have just passed increment multiple
    indices(j) = i - 1;                % previous index is what we want
    while(cumdist_km(i) > j * km_increment) % handle case value skips ahead
                  % note: well end up with a NaN in indices for every skip
      j = j + 1   % normal is 1 increment. skip is > 1
    end
  end
end
indices(end) = length(cumdist_km);
```

Then back in your main script you could do:

```
five_km_indices = findIndicesBelowIncrement(cumdist_km, 5);
dist_5kminc = cumdist_km(five_km_indices);
elev_5kminc = elevations(five_km_indices);
```

Then do whatever calculations on dist_5kminc and elev_5kminc.